# Is it related to Windows 10 update?

Tags: windows-10, bios, windows-update, troubleshooting, uuid

My Windows 10 wasn't updating so I checked the UUID of BIOS which was all zeroes.
Also, I used this code snippet to check it in Windows itself.

```
wmic path win32_computersystemproduct get UUID.
```

And I got UUID all zero:
[image: Here's the image.]

Is this the main reason for Windows 10 not updating? In the update section in settings I see this:

> An update is being prepared for your device, but it's not quite ready yet. We'll keep trying or you can try again now.

I ran troubleshooter, but no improvement. It shows the problems are fixed (except for some), but in reality they are not.

[image: Troubleshooter Image]

Comment: What version of Windows 10 do you have? 1607? Have you tried using the [Windows Update Assistant](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/windows-10-update-assistant-3550dfb2-a015-7765-12ea-fba2ac36fb3f) and get further up in the feature updates? Depends on what version you are running - they will not get update without feature updates.

Comment: @Darius, I tried to update using Windows Update Assistant but it fails with a long error code. It downloads the Windows, proceeds with the installation but during the installation after reboot, it fails and recovers the older version of windows which I have (Windows 10 Home Single Language 1709).

Comment: I tried to solve that error every way. I followed the official Microsoft guide, various forums, etc. but it yielded no results. This left me suspicious that the problem might be the cause of the nulled UUID.